# acro package: Italicize first occurrence of term

Tags: acronyms

I am using the `acro` package for acronyms because, for a phrase that is not a proper name, I can have the first letter of each word uncapitalized except when it starts off a sentence, in which case the very first letter of the phrase is capitalized. Like other packages, it allows user-specification of plural forms for the acronym and the long phrase. Unlike other packages, it provides these capabilities without having to externally make an index. It is not a full fledge glossary package, but it meets my needs for acronyms.

For the `acro` package, is there a way to italicize the first occurrence of the phrase, when the acronym is introduced, but without italicizing the acronym itself? The vanilla way of introducing a phrase and its acronym is `\ac{label}`, which expands to the phrase followed by its acronym in brackets. The command `\textit{\ac{label}}` causes both the phrase and the acronym to be italicized.

I know that the `acronym` package (as opposed to the `acro` package) does the proper italicization with `\acfi{label}`, at least according to ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/pub//tex/macros/lat ... cronym.pdf. However, this is not recognized using the `acro` package.

I'm not sure if a MWE is needed for this question, but here is a toy
file:

```
  \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage{acro}
     \DeclareAcronym{abc}{
        short=ABC,
        long=alpha bettick crisps
     }
  \begin{document}

     The objective of this report is to test acronyms like
     \ac{abc}.  \acresetall \Ac{abc} are delicious.

     \acresetall
     \textit{\ac{abc}}.

     \cleardoublepage
     \printacronyms[%
        name = {Abbreviations},
        sort = false
     ]

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `format/first-long` key wich controls the format for the long form on first usage (with `\ac`, `\acf` or `\acflike` and their uppercase, plural and indefinite forms).

```
\acsetup{format/first-long=\itshape}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{abc}{
  short=ABC,
  long=alpha bettick crisps
}

\acsetup{format/first-long=\itshape}

\begin{document}

The objective of this report is to test acronyms like
\ac{abc}.  \acresetall\Ac{abc} are delicious.

\ac{abc}.

\cleardoublepage
\printacronyms[%
  name = {Abbreviations},
  sort = false,
]

\end{document}
```

The text in the document:

[image]

The entry in the list:

[image]

Using

```
\acsetup{format/first-long=\itshape}
```

will italicize the long form of the acronym everywhere (including the list of acronyms).

One can do this on a per acronym basis (thanks to **cgnieder**) using the `format/first-long` or `long-format` keys in the acronym declaration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{abc}{
  short=ABC,
  long=alpha bettick crisps
}
\DeclareAcronym{def}{
  short=DEF,
  long=delta elphic furs,
  format/first-long=\itshape
}

\begin{document}

The objective of this report is to test acronyms like
\ac{abc}.  \acresetall\Ac{abc} are delicious.
The objective of this report is to test acronyms like
\ac{def}.  \acresetall\Ac{def} are delicious.

\cleardoublepage
\printacronyms[%
  name = {Abbreviations},
  sort = false,
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Gonzalo.  At the risk of sounding demanding, I don't suppose one could control this on a per-acronym basis?  I don't think its needed when the long phrase is a proper name.  And there are some times when I don't want to emphatically pound the table (so to speak), which italics looks like.

P.S.  This thread is crossposted at http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=23865

P.P.S. Odd that a carriage return is interpretted as clicking on the post submission button when composing here.

Comment: @user36800 you can switch styles at desired points in your document. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @user36800 you can specify `long-format=<whatever>` on a per acronym basis by setting it in `\DeclareAcronym`: `\DeclareAcronym{aa}{
  short = aa ,
  long  = AAAAAA ,
  long-format = \itshape
}`

Comment: @cgnieder Ah.... mind if I add that to my answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina feel free to add it :)

Comment: BTW: One can also add `first-long-format` on a per acronym basis. (IIRC this acts in addition to a possibly specified `long-format` and not as a replacement.)

Comment: @cgnieder added. Thanks! By the way, lately I've seen some of your recent packages; unfortunately I haven't had the time to look at them in detail, but they are great!