# Get acronym withpage to work with \acfi instead of \ac

Tags: formatting, acronyms

I am trying to format my acronyms and want to use `\acfi` instead of `\ac` (which makes the word italic).

The problem is, `withpage` seems to work only for the `\ac` command, so the page information for acronyms introduced with `\acfi`.

*Is there a way to add the `acfi` command to the withpage option? Or is there an easier solution for this?* I've found this Post, but it does not solve my issue: [acro package: Italicize first occurrence of term](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133674/acro-package-italicize-first-occurrence-of-term)

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}

\begin{document} 

\section{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[Bash]
 \acro{A}{Apple}
 \acro{B}{Ball}
 \acro{C}{Cat}
\end{acronym}

This an \ac{A}, this is a \acfi{B}, but I can't think of a word with C.

This is the \acs{A}\acs{B}\acs{C}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: Result]

*As this is my first Tex question, I wonder if there is a way to add a running example + output directly?*

Comment: I would recommend considering switching to the [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package and using the answer you link to - I find [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) much more powerful while being very similar to [`acronym`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) at the more basic levels.

Comment: @DaiBowen thanks for the hint, I will have a look at it. What may be the major improvements i your eyes?

Comment: The main thing which got me was the `\Ac` variants which printed a capitalised version (i.e. so you could use `\Ac{foo}` when starting a new sentence).  More generally it has more user access to do things like `\acreset{foo}` which resets `foo` as being unused (e.g. if you want all acronyms to be defined in each chapter) there's no equivalent user interface for doing that with `acroynm`.  Probably the most impressive thing is the flexibility you have in printing the list of acronyms which is so much greater.  All the while, the `\ac` and friends are defined and work in `acro` as in `acronym`.

Comment: So I will definitely have a look at it, thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\acfi` macro calls `\acfi` which is defined as

```
\newcommand{\acfia}[1]{%
  {\itshape \AC@acl{#1} \nolinebreak[3]} (\ifAC@starred\acs*{#1}\else\acs{#1}\fi)}
```

Comparing this with the internal definition for `\acf`

```
\newcommand*{\@acf}[1]{%
    \ifAC@footnote
       \acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}}%
       \footnote{\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}{}}%
    \else
       \acffont{%
          \AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}%
          \nolinebreak[3] %
          \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}})}%
        }%
     \fi
     \ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#1}\fi}
```

We see that `\acfia` seems to be lacking the `\AC@placelabel{#1}` which appears to be responsible for producing the label.

Adding this in to the definition as (I've also played with the spacing as I think there above definition has two spaces between the long and short versions)

```
\renewcommand{\acfia}[1]{%
    {\itshape\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}\nolinebreak[3] }(\ifAC@starred\acs*{#1}\else\acs{#1}\fi)%
}
```

Running this then creates the label, it also causes the acronym to be marked as used (with the initial definition of `\acfia`, `\acfi{B} \ac{B}` becomes "*Ball* (B) Ball (B)" whereas using the redefinition above the same yields "*Ball* (B) B".

In a full document

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\acfia}[1]{%
    {\itshape\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}\nolinebreak[3] }(\ifAC@starred\acs*{#1}\else\acs{#1}\fi)%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\section{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[Bash]
 \acro{A}{Apple}
 \acro{B}{Ball}
 \acro{C}{Cat}
\end{acronym}

This an \ac{A}, this is a \acfi{B}, but I can't think of a word with C.

This is the \acs{A}\acs{B}\acs{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]