# \acfi - an italic full definition in the acro package

Tags: acronyms, acro

I noticed that the `\acfi{LSTM}` macro, which I know from the `acronym` package, is, however, not available in the `acro` package. It styles the full definition italic like:

> *long short-term memory* (LSTM)

I came across [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133674/acro-package-italicize-first-occurrence-of-term) *"acro package: Italicize first occurrence of term"* where all the first occurrences of an abbreviation are italicized via

```
\acsetup{first-long-format=\itshape}
```

However, as I only want to highlight specific terms and work with reintroductions of terms, this doesn't help in my use case -- as I need the full flexibility. Which options are available to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional argument to `\acf`:

```
\acf[format/long=\itshape]{LSTM}
```

or define a command for this yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{LTSM}{
  short = LTSM ,
  long  = long short-term memory
}

\newcommand\acfi[2][]{\acf[#1,format/long=\itshape]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\acf[format/long=\itshape]{LTSM}

\acfi{LTSM}

\end{document}
```

[image]